# Rails - Searching for messages and conversations. How to show only the latest message of each conversation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I created a messaging system for my Rails app using this tutorial: [Create a Simple Messaging System on Rails](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1#.r20m5jryc), by Dana Mulder. It works wonders, but I am having a problem in tweaking it a little bit. **Would anyone have insight in creating a conversations inbox that shows the latest message of each conversation?** More details follow.

There are two models in the system: Conversation and Message:

- A Conversation has a user1_id and a user2_id.
- A Message has a user_id, body, and conversation_id.

Thus, each conversation can have multiple messages, and each message belongs to the user who sent it.

I built a ConversationsController that shows all messages in the index. **What I want, though, is one that only shows the latest message of each conversation, in order.**

I'm going to paste here the current version of the Conversations#Index action, and the one I'm envisioning (which creates a mistake that I'll describe below).

**Working Conversations#Index (displays all messages):**

```
@conversations = Conversation.where("user1_id = #{current_user.id} OR user2_id = #{current_user.id}")

@array = []
@conversations.each do |item|
    @array.push(item.id)
end
@messages = Message.where("conversation_id in (?)",  @array)
```

**Not working Conversations#Index (SHOULD display only latest message of each conversation:**

```
@conversations = Conversation.where("user1_id = #{current_user.id} OR user2_id = #{current_user.id}").order("updated_at DESC")

@array = []
@conversations.each do |item|
    @array.push(item.id)
end

@list = []
@array.each do |i|
    @id = Message.where("conversation_id = (?)", i).last
    @list.push(@id.id)
end

@messages = Message.where("id in (?)", @list)
```

When I enter the latter piece of code, the inbox shows no messages at all. Any ideas why?

**Logs**

```
    Started GET "/conversations" for 99.234.104.113 at 2016-05-14 04:19:05 +0000
Processing by ConversationsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Conversation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE (1 IN (sender_id, recipient_id))  ORDER BY updated_at DESC
  Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE (conversation_id = 2)  ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE (conversation_id = 1)  ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "conversations" WHERE (1 IN (sender_id, recipient_id))
  Conversation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE (1 IN (sender_id, recipient_id))  ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered conversations/_convo.html.erb (150.4ms)
  Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE (id in (10,9)) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Rendered conversations/_message.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered conversations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (157.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 299ms (Views: 292.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong field names in the query.  Try this:

```
@conversations = Conversation.
  where("user1_id = #{current_user.id} OR user2_id = #{current_user.id}").
  order("updated_at DESC")
```

This should get you going with that query.  It's always good to show the console log for something like this, as well, so that the execution of the action can be followed.

To make an improvement on your query, you can use query parameters.  They let you include the values that you want without using string interpolation (which could potentially lead to [SQL injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection) issue).  You can do something like this:

```
@conversations = Conversation.
  where("user1_id = ? OR user2_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id).
  order("updated_at DESC")
```

And, you can shorten the same query just a bit by using an IN operator and taking fewer parameters:

```
@conversations = Conversation.
  where("? IN (user1_id, user2_id)", current_user.id).
  order("updated_at DESC")
```

For the rest of your method, here are a few changes that might improve the performance and reduce the code a bit:

```
@messages = Message.
  where(conversation_id: @conversations).
  group(:conversation_id).
  having("id = MAX(id)")
```

The first line builds an array of `item.id`s from all of the conversations in @conversations.  This uses the Ruby [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) method to accomplish the task efficiently.

The second line uses hash arguments to `where` to achieve a tighter query by using ActiveRecord to generate a SQL IN clause (See the [Hash Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) section of the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more information).  It then groups the messages by `conversation_id` and filters the latest with a `having` clause.

Also note that you don't have to use @ variables unless you're communicating them implicitly elsewhere, such as to the view or other methods in the same class.  Local variables can just have regular names like `array` and `messages`.

Comment: Does not solve the problem, but makes it much more eloquent. Thank you very much. The first thing you pointed out (user1 instead of user1_id) was a typo only here on StackOverflow, so I'm still having the problem. I would appreciate immensely if you could still take a look at the problem and see if you can help me find a solution. Again, many thanks :)

Comment: No problem.  Questions: Do you need to use @conversations, or is it just to find the messages?  Can you post the logs for the action, so that I can see the parameters, the generated SQL and the other action details?

Comment: I do need @conversations, and adding the logs to the question. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the query for @messages.  Give that a try and see if it returns the messages that you expect.

Comment: Just pass the collection to where `Message.where(conversation_id: @conversations)` - ActiveRecord will convert it to an array of ids on its own.

Comment: Turns out the error was in the view (I loathe myself), and your suggestions worked after all. Hero!

Answer (score 2):

I would start by creating a proper M2M relationship between `User` and `Conversation` as the tutorial leaves quite a bit to be desired:

- conversations are limited to 2 users by design
- since conversations stores both of the user foreign keys on the same row you need those kludgy `IF a_id = :id OR b_id = :id` queries and overly complicated relationships.

## A better domain model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, 
           through: :user_conversations
end

# this is the join table between users and conversations
class UserConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :users, 
           through: :user_conversations
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can create the UserConversation model and migration with:

```
rails g model UserConversation user:belongs_to conversation:belongs_to
```

You will also want to create a migration to get rid of the uneeded `conversations.user1_id` and `conversations.user2_id` columns - [see the rails guides for how do that](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

## Putting the associations to use

This will let us get conversations by:

```
@conversations = current_user.conversations
```

Fetching one message per conversation can be done by applying group and order to the query:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation

  def self.recent(conversations)
    self.order(:conversation_id, :created_at)
        .group(:conversation_id)
        .where(conversation_id: conversations)
  end
end
```

So to bring this together in your controller you would do:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @conversations = current_user.conversations
    @recent_messages = Message.recent(@conversations)
  end
end
```

See:

- [Rails Guides: Active Record Associations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: IMHO thats a pretty bad tutorial - she falls in every noob trap ever on a domain that literally has been done to death.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, max. Would you please expand on the views and controllers in such case? It would be a pleasure to work on a better tutorial, and I'd obviously credit you 100%.

Comment: Hmm, its kind of hard to go on - it might be better if you post a follow up question on a specific part of the problem. The stackoverflow format does not really lend itself well to long tutorial style answers.